# Creating graph from a matrix.

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have an n.n matrix, like the following picture and I want to create a graph that shows me the relationship between them.

[image]

In this case that is a real case, I have 4 column that contains traffic flow of a computer network, and the elements ere [Source IPs, Source Ports, Destination IPs, Destination Ports],
As I did a little bit of search about this issue, I can use R studio and "ggplot" function.
I have two questions and I would appreciate you in advance if you can help me to do this job or at least give me more hint or clue to do it.
The first question is how to create a graph from a matrix?
The second question is how can I do I practically like using software like RStudio?

Comment: First note that in a undirected graph, the matrix will be symmetric. This is the case in your example. So, you only have to consider indices $(i, j)$ with $j \ge i;$ i.e., the upper triangle of the matrix. Indices with $i = j$ (along the main diagonal) represent edges starting and ending at the same vertex. Just connect each pair of nodes with nonzero value, and you're done.

Comment: @K.Jiang I made some mistakes, an IP can have a connection with other IPs using different ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out
[the Graphviz graph layout and visualization package](https://graphviz.org/)

Using your example data, the directed graph
can be described as `ip.dot` file:

```
digraph{
  splines=true;
  rankdir=LR;
  "X.X.1.2:46564" -> "192.168.12.12:8080"
  "X.X.1.3:46547" -> "192.168.20.20:443"
  "X.X.1.4:32131" -> "192.168.15.2:80"
  "X.X.1.2:12456" -> "192.168.15.2:80"
  "X.X.1.5:65231" -> "192.168.20.20:443"
  "X.X.1.2:52461" -> "192.168.42.13:6513"
  "X.X.1.5:48532" -> "192.168.15.2:80"
  "X.X.1.5:15246" -> "192.168.20.20:443"
  "X.X.1.4:16542" -> "192.168.1.12:135"
  "X.X.1.4:68452" -> "192.168.15.2:80"
  "X.X.1.2:46813" -> "192.168.1.12:135"
  "X.X.1.2:16895" -> "192.168.20.20:443"
  "X.X.1.7:36555" -> "192.168.15.2:80"
}
```

and the `dot -Tps ip.dot` command generates a graph

[image]